# Reference for the notion of "dimension" in incidence geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, axiomatic-geometry

Consider an incidence geometry as in an elementary course on geometry. The german wikipedia

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inzidenzgeometrie

mentions a well defined notion of "dimension". Does anybody know of a good reference?
The literature given at the end of the wiki-page seems to deal only with the well known case of affine and projective geometry.

Comment: What's the intention behind that reference you're looking for? Do you want something in English because of language problems with German Wikipedia? Do you want something more in-depth than that article, to follow up on the subject? Or do you want a more well-established text more suitable as a scientific citation? Depending on the motivation here, I can imagine different kinds of answers. If it were the first, people might translate the German Wikipedia.

Comment: First of all I'm interested in a precise statement. Is it: Two sets of independent generators have the same cardinality? I'm not quite sure, but if this is it, I'm interested in a proof. In the "dimension game" you usually add more axioms (exchange property, matroids,...), but maybe just to exclude examples like the one given on this wiki page ("Unterschiede zur Euklidischen Geometri").

Answer (score 0):

You mention in a comment that you are primarily interested in a precise statement. I believe the Wikipedia article has one, so I'll translate that to English and add a bit of notation.

The **incidence geometry** is defined by a set of points $P$, a set of lines (or blocks) $B$, and an incidence relation $I\subset P\times B$. Each pair of distinct points is incident with exactly one line:

$$\forall p,q\in P:p\neq q\rightarrow\dot\exists g\in B:\bigl((p,g)\in I\wedge(q,g)\in I\bigr)$$

A subset $M\subset P$ is called a **linear set** iff

$$\forall p,q\in M,r\in P,g\in B:\bigl((p,g)\in I\wedge(q,g)\in I\wedge(r,g)\in I\bigr)\rightarrow r\in M$$

So for every two points in $M$, if they are incident with a line $g$, then any (other) point $r$ incident with that same line has to be in $M$ as well.

The **linear hull** $\langle M\rangle$ of a set $M\subset P$ is the intersection of all linear sets containing $M$. In (ugly-looking) formula:

$$\langle M\rangle:=\bigcap_{\substack{N\subset P\\M\subset N\\N\text{ is linear set}}}N$$

If $M$ is already a linear set, $\langle M\rangle$ is just $M$ itself. Otherwise you can picture that for every pair of points in the set, you add all the points on the lines joining them, repeatedly until you reached a fixed point.

Now $M\subset P$ is a **basis** of $P$ iff $\langle M\rangle=P$ and there is no smaller set with that property, i.e.

$$\langle M\rangle=P\wedge \neg\exists N\subset P:\left(\lvert N\rvert<\lvert M\rvert\wedge\langle N\rangle=P\right)$$

The **dimension** of the geometry is the size of the basis minus one, i.e. $\lvert M\rvert-1$.

> Is it: Two sets of independent generators have the same cardinality?

Not necessarily, which I believe is the reason why the definition of the basis explicitly requires it to be of minimal cardinality.

I'm not sure what you mean by “independent”, so the subsequent text here is just ignoring that word. You can add arbitrary additional points to any generater of the whole geometry, and again end up with a generator. I guess this much is fairly intuitive, and shows that generators can come in different cardinalities.

The question becomes more interesting if you consider “local minima”: start with a generator of $P$, then remove points until you can remove no more points without loosing that generator property. In formula, look for an $M$ such that

$$\langle M\rangle=P\wedge \neg\exists N\subsetneq M:\langle N\rangle=P$$

In a way, such a subset would be locally minimal: you could not make it smaller just by removing points. The interesting question here would be, would each such locally minimal generator be globally minimal and hence a basis?

I will see whether I can come up with an example where this is not the case, or an idea of why this will always be the case.

Comment: It is indeed not difficult to find an example for your 'not necessarily' after the quote. Well, I will certainly not call this wiki-page one of the best I ever saw. Thank you again, bye.